# Selecting description of 12 hour time period SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I am writing a query for a report in which I need to select if the time period falls into the "Day" or "Night". The table I wish to select from looks like this:

`DAYNIGHT_TABLE`:

```
Description | StartTime        | EndTime
Night       | 18:00:00.0000000 | 06:00:00.0000000
Day         | 06:00:00.0000000 | 18:00:00.0000000
```

For different customers this may be broken up further into smaller time slots but as a starting point I just need to select `Day` or `Night` based on a datetime that I retrieve from another table.

If I do something like this then I only get day:

```
SELECT Description
FROM Table s
WHERE convert(TIME,myTable.MyDateTime) >= s.StartTime
  AND convert(TIME,myTable.MyDateTime) < s.StartTime
```

I feel like I am missing something obvious here but how can I retrieve the Day/Night Description from `DAYNIGHT_TABLE` based on the known time from myTable.MyDateTime?

Comment: Try `DATEPART(hour, myTable.MyDateTime)`

Comment: What is your expected o/p

Comment: @Backtrack I would like to get either **Day** or **Night** for any given time from myTable.MyDateTime (Which I am fetching from a different query). Note that DAYNIGHT_TABLE may be extended to have an Afternoon and/or Morning row.

Comment: @artm I can use `DATEPART(hour, myTable.MyDateTime)` with `TOP 1` to get the first occurrence. But how can I get the values between 00:00:00 and 06:00:00 correctly as **Night**?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you can't touch the `DAYNIGHT_TABLE` table at all, read below.

---

Since all you need is a label "Day" or "Night" I would recommend to alter your `DAYNIGHT_TABLE` table and include one more row into it, so that no range of times in any row goes across the midnight. It makes query much simpler and efficient:

```
DAYNIGHT_TABLE:

Description | StartTime        | EndTime
Night       | 18:00:00.0000000 | 00:00:00.0000000
Night       | 00:00:00.0000000 | 06:00:00.0000000
Day         | 06:00:00.0000000 | 18:00:00.0000000
```

Also, make sure that you consistently assume which end of the interval is inclusive and which is exclusive. I'll assume that it is `[StartTime; EndTime)`, i.e. `StartTime` inclusive and `EndTime` exclusive.

Have an index on `StartTime DESC` with `Description` as included column. It is not really needed and with so few rows in `DAYNIGHT_TABLE` you would likely not notice any difference, but still.

Now, if you have a table `myTable` with column `MyDateTime` and you want to get correct matching description from `DAYNIGHT_TABLE`, use something like this:

```
SELECT
    myTable.MyDateTime
    ,CA.Description
FROM
    myTable
    CROSS APPLY
    (
        SELECT TOP(1) DAYNIGHT_TABLE.Description
        FROM DAYNIGHT_TABLE
        WHERE DAYNIGHT_TABLE.StartTime <= CAST(myTable.MyDateTime AS time)
        ORDER BY DAYNIGHT_TABLE.StartTime DESC
    ) AS CA
```

For every row in `myTable` `CROSS APPLY` would find one matching Description.

Make sure that intervals in `DAYNIGHT_TABLE` cover all 24 hours without gaps.

Notice, that query doesn't use `EndTime` at all, because it assumes that intervals in the table cover full 24 hours. So, you can remove this column from the table and it will look like this:

```
Description | StartTime        
Night       | 00:00:00.0000000 
Day         | 06:00:00.0000000 
Night       | 18:00:00.0000000
```

With such table that has these two columns the only index that is needed is just a unique clustered primary key on `StartTime`.

---

If you can't touch the `DAYNIGHT_TABLE` table at all, but if you still can guarantee that intervals in the table (a) don't overlap, (b) don't have gaps, (c) cover full 24 hours, then there will be one extra step in the query.

If all conditions outlined above hold true, then there can be at most only one row that spans across midnight, which means that its `StartTime` is greater than its `EndTime`. This is how we can find it and take care of it. Again, I assume that `StartTime` is inclusive and `EndTime` is exclusive.

```
DECLARE @DAYNIGHT_TABLE TABLE(Description varchar(50), StartTime time, EndTime time);

INSERT INTO @DAYNIGHT_TABLE(Description, StartTime, EndTime) VALUES 
('Night', '18:00:00', '06:00:00'),
('Day', '06:00:00', '18:00:00');

DECLARE @myTable TABLE(MyDateTime datetime);
INSERT INTO @myTable (MyDateTime) VALUES
('2015-01-01 00:00:00'),
('2015-01-01 02:02:02'),
('2015-01-01 06:00:00'),
('2015-01-01 12:02:02'),
('2015-01-01 18:00:00'),
('2015-01-01 22:02:02');

WITH
CTE_TimeIntervals
AS
(
    SELECT
        Description
        ,StartTime
    FROM @DAYNIGHT_TABLE AS DAYNIGHT_TABLE

    UNION ALL

    SELECT
        Description
        ,CAST('00:00:00' AS time) AS StartTime
    FROM @DAYNIGHT_TABLE AS DAYNIGHT_TABLE
    WHERE StartTime >= EndTime
)
SELECT
    myTable.MyDateTime
    ,CA.Description
FROM
    @myTable AS myTable
    CROSS APPLY
    (
        SELECT TOP(1) CTE_TimeIntervals.Description
        FROM CTE_TimeIntervals
        WHERE CTE_TimeIntervals.StartTime <= CAST(myTable.MyDateTime AS time)
        ORDER BY CTE_TimeIntervals.StartTime DESC
    ) AS CA
```

**Result set**

```
MyDateTime                 Description
2015-01-01 00:00:00.000    Night
2015-01-01 02:02:02.000    Night
2015-01-01 06:00:00.000    Day
2015-01-01 12:02:02.000    Day
2015-01-01 18:00:00.000    Night
2015-01-01 22:02:02.000    Night
```

Comment: While I really like the idea of altering the DAYNIGHT_TABLE, I don't think I am in a position to do so. Also, other time periods may be added where I have no control. These may also span over midnight and cause the same problem. Ideally I would like to adopt this solution but I have to give artm the tick because it is the solution that I have used.

Comment: If you have no control of other periods that may be added, can you still guarantee that intervals in `DAYNIGHT_TABLE` (a) don't overlap, (b) don't have gaps, (c) cover full 24 hours? To make my query work the structure of the table doesn't need to be changed (the EndTime is simply ignored), all is needed is to split one row that spans over midnight into two rows that go up to midnight and from midnight. If you don't want to persist this split it is possible to make a view that does it on the fly, but efficiency would be worse of course.

Comment: Besides, my approach doesn't care if the interval starts and ends at the beginning of the hour, it could be any moment in time. The "Lunch break" may easily start at `11:43:56` and end at `13:02:17`.

Comment: I will have to get back to you tomorrow after I have a chance to investigate.

Comment: @McGee, I've extended the answer, it will work with your original table, but less efficiently.

Comment: Your second answer is right for my situation. Thank you for such a thorough explanation.

Answer (score 1):

You need somthing like this, test it with different values:

http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d6328/1/0

```
select s1.myDate, t.Descr
from s s1
inner join DAYNIGHT_TABLE t on datepart(hour, s1.myDate) >= datepart(hour, t.StartTime) 
AND datepart(hour, s1.myDate) < datepart(hour, t.EndTime) 
OR ((t.EndTime < t.StartTime) AND ( datepart(hour, s1.myDate) >= datepart(hour, t.StartTime)) AND datepart(hour, s1.mydate) < (datepart(hour, t.StartTime) + datepart(hour, t.EndTime)))
```

Comment: That is awesome. Only problem is it still returns nulls for 00:00 -> 06:00

Comment: With a little modification, this got me through. Thanks a lot mate.